# TypeError in Python (pycharm)

Tags: python, typeerror

What should I change in my code to avoid TypeError?

```
n=5
print("*"*n)
for i in range(n-2,0,-2):
    print(" "*((n-i)/2)+"*"*i)
```

> ```
> *TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'*
> ```

Comment: This has nothing to do with pycharm. What do you expect `print(" "*((n-i)/2)+"*"*i)` to do?

Comment: You probably want to do floor division `((n-i)//2)`

Comment: "What should I change in my code to avoid TypeError?" Delete your code. Facetiousness aside, those kinds of questions are uselessly vague unless you tell us what you're actually trying to accomplish

Comment: See how to create a [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here:

```
  print(" "*((n-i)/2)+"*"*i)
```

Since you have `((n-i)/2)`, you have a floating point result.  If you reinterpret that as an integer, you'll be fine:

```
  print(" "*(int((n-i)/2))+"*"*i)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need integer value for string multiplication:

```
n=5
print("*" * n)
for i in range(n-2,0,-2):
    print(" " * ((n-i) // 2) + "*" * i)
```